# Pass data to activity android

Tags: android, android-activity, share

Good day.I have an question to which i could not find an answer.I want to pass an data to an activity but i must say that i do not want to use intents as it is not aplicable to my situation.The situation is the next.Imagine an builder class which builds ui colors by specified beforehand colors.As soon as 3rd party developer done building the builder,i must start an activity with the values that the developer input in the builder.The issue is that i have lets say 10 activities,and all the activities must access that single color variable.For that purpose,the intents is hard to get done as it is not better idea to pas single variable over and over and over to each activity,i have though about inheritance,like have an base class for all activities and all of them will inherit from single class,but the issue part is that whenever i have an setter and getter inside the base class,and as soon as the developer set the according color,and i have called the setter method from the base class and started according activity,the activity will just never get the variable,it always 0,which means the variable is not set..But how it can be?
Is there any way to achieve what i want?

Comment: Search for `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: neither that is applicable as i do not want to give that such access to 3rd party developer,but want to manipulate all in my sdk